# Error: Error: Redis connection gone from close event

Tags: redis, node-redis

while running following code

```
for (var i= 0; i< 20; i++) {
        redisClient.lindex("devices", i, function (errorMessage, DeviceList) {
          for (var j= 0; j< 20; j++) {
              var deviceCoordinateList = resultData[j].split(',');
              var deviceCoordinate = deviceCoordinateList[0]+i+ ','+deviceCoordinateList [1]+i;
              redisClient.lpush(DeviceList, deviceCoordinate, redisInitialise.print);
            }
        });
    }
```

i am getting the error:

```
Error: Error: Redis connection gone from close event.
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429020/redis-connection-gone-from-close-event)?

Comment: yes, i tried this one but still showing same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might be doing something wrong.
I think you are writing redis quit() function at wrong place

```
redisClient.quit();
```